# MKMapView panning causes parent UIScrollView to scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a MKMapView added to a UIScrollView. I thought that the expected functionality would be that panning the map would cause the map to move, but it's parent UIScrollView would not scroll. i.e. if you were panning the map, the scrollview would stay in it's current position.

This is my code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height)];
    [scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    double mapHeight = 200;
    if([AppDelegate isRunningOniPad])
        mapHeight = 400;

    map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.width, mapHeight)];
    [map setExclusiveTouch:NO];
    [scrollView map];
```

I've tried setting exclusive touch to YES and to NO, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to get the behaviour working so that panning the map will stop the UIScrollView from moving? I've tried changing map to a UIScrollView instead of an MKMapView too, but that had the same behaviour - so I doubt that this is MKMapView specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected outcome is correct, the scroll view should remain stationary when the Map View is touched, as this should receive the touch events before they are passed up the responder chain to the scroll view.

I have quickly tested the above code in an empty project, and this is working as expected with a couple of alterations to the creating of frame & sizes, iPad size detection, and adding the map as a sub-view of the scroll view.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
// Make the content size large to allow scroll view to move
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 2000)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

double mapHeight = 200;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    mapHeight = 400;
}

MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, mapHeight)];
[map setExclusiveTouch:NO];
[scrollView addSubview:map];
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've created a couple of demo projects too and I see the correct behaviour - just as you say. So I removed my class completely and replaced it with an empty class with the code you posted in the viewDidLoad. The same still happens in my project however... but the exact same class works fine in other projects, so I am really confused.

Comment: And as far as I can see, it has nothing to do with the fact that the view is inside a tab view controller or a navigation controller. It behaves the same if it is added without these.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the the project that disables the user interaction with the MKMapView? as this would prevent the touches being detected by the map view & passed to the scroll view. Using Tab/Navigation controllers should not make a difference, as the scroll & map views are sub views of them.

Comment: No - I've tried doing what you do and just declaring the map locally in the init or viewDidLoad, so nothing else has access to it after it has been created. I didn't think the tab/nav controllers would make a difference but I don't know what is happening so thought I would try it!

Comment: Thanks for your help - it turned out to be a bug with the DAKeyboardControl I was using in my project. I've raised a bug with the control on github here - https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone,

Adding a `MKMapView` to a `UIScrollView` should work as expected. In my situation, it wasn't working because my view hierarchy was setup incorrectly.

If you're having problems look at how you are adding sub views (ie `[self.view addSubview:mapView]`. Make sure the `MKMapView` is properly in the `UIScrollView`'s hierarchy.

Also, I really like revealapp.com to inspecting the view hierarchy (and no I'm not associated with them ;)